# Is there a way to obtain exactly 2 quarts in the 8-quart or 5-quart pitcher?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Suppose we are given pitchers of waters, of sizes $12$ quarts, $8$ quarts, and $5$ quarts. Initially the $12$ quart pitcher is full and the other two empty. We can pour water from one pitcher to another, pouring until the receiving pitcher is full or the pouring pitcher is empty. Is there a way to pour among pitchers to obtain exactly $2$ quarts in the $8$-quart or $5$-quart pitcher? If so, find the minimal sequence of pourings to get $2$ quarts in the $8$-quart or the $5$-quart pitcher.

My work:

Start at $(12,0,0)$

Can either go to $(7,0,5)$ or $(4,8,0)$

From $(7,0,5)$ you can go to $(0,7,5)$ or $(7,5,0)$

From $(4,8,0)$ you can go to $(0,8,4)$ or $(4,3,5)$

After this I'm kind of confused as to where to go with this. The answer in the back of the textbook says (listed as $(b,c)$) -> $(0,0)-(0,5)-(7,5)$. This answer doesn't make any sense to me and I don't know if it is correct. Am I missing something?

Edit: New thoughts are $(12,0,0)$ to $(7,0,5)$ to $(0,7,5)$ to $(5,7,0)$ to $(5,2,5)$ Is this the shortest way to solve this problem?

Comment: Should be $(7,0,5)$ to begin with.

Comment: Are you allowed to halve volumes? If so, try $(12,0,0)$ to $(4,8,0)$ to $(2,8,2)$ because you can visually determine when pitchers $a$ and $c$ have the same amount.

Comment: If not your new solution is the shortest I've come up with yet.

Comment: @Lanier That only works if all pitchers have the same cross-sectional area.

Comment: I don't think we can halve I'm pretty sure you need to pour all of the water in or pour until the other pitcher is full.

Comment: Okay, then your answer should be correct, as it matches the steps in your book's appendices.

Answer (score 1):

I would go to (7, 0, 5), then (7, 5, 0), (2, 5, 5) and (2, 8, 2).  This is four pours.